# I get NaN with a divison function with a variable in denominator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Java and I've been tackling this problem for a few days now and I can't figure it out.
The gauge returns NaN result with the following error in development console:

> : DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid selector. at Error (native) at htttp...cantposthttp...ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:5:28399
>   code: 12
>   message: "Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid selector."
>   name: "SyntaxError"
>   stack: "Error: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid selector.↵ at Error (native)↵ at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:5:28399"
>   **proto**: DOMException
>   e: (e)
>   t: div
>   this: Window

The Code:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'  src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      // set your channel id here
      var channel_id = xxxxx;
  // set your channel's read api key here if necessary
  var api_key = 'xxxxxxx';
  // maximum value for the gauge
  //var max_gauge_value = 13;
  // name of the gauge
  var gauge_name = 'VPD';

  // global variables
  var chart, charts, data;

  // load the google gauge visualization
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(initChart);



  // display the data
  function displayData(point) {

    data.setValue(0, 0, gauge_name);
    data.setValue(0, 1, point);
    chart.draw(data, options);




  }


  // load the data
  function loadData() {
    // variable for the data point




    // get the data from thingspeak
    $.getJSON('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/' + channel_id + '/feed/last.json?api_key=' + api_key, function(data) {

      // get the data point
      var t = data.field1;
      var h = data.field2;




      function myFunction(a) {


        return (a * 7.5)/(237.5 + a);
      }





      // if there is a data point display it
      if (t) {
        t = myFunction(t);

        displayData(t);

      }


      });
  }



  // initialize the chart
  function initChart() {


    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addRows(1);

    chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div'));
    options = {width: 240, height: 240, majorTicks:["0","0.5","1","1.5","2","2.5","3","3.5","4"], max: 13, redFrom: 1.4, redTo: 13, yellowFrom:1, yellowTo:1.4, minorTicks: 5};

    loadData();

    // load new data every 15 seconds
    setInterval('loadData()', 15000);
  }
</script>
```

Thank you for your help!

Matej

Comment: *"I'm new to Java"* Java and JavaScript are different languages.

Comment: there is no error-related code in your question

Comment: T.J. sorry, should have said I'm not skilled in programming at all >newbie:) Dr.Molle that's all I get in development tools, where should I look?

Comment: Maybe I should mention that if I change this function:
function myFunction(a) {
        return (a * 7.5)/(237.5 + a);
      }

to this(removing a variable in denominator):

function myFunction(a) {
        return (a * 7.5) / 237.5;
      }

this function then works and puts out a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved the problem, which was that the data logger was sending data in strings not in numbers, so I converted strings into integers and the thing now works.

I changed this:

```
// get the data point
      var t = data.field1;
      var h = data.field2;
```

to this:

```
// get the data point
          var t = +(data.field1);
          var h = +(data.field2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message

> .../jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:5:28399 code: 12 message: "Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': ',:x' is not a valid selector."

is a red herring. It comes from a bug in jQuery code.

I noticed this same message, and I searched the web for it. People complain about it in various different contexts.

In my case, I fixed the actual problem, while this jQuery bug stays.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you've set the variable channel_id correctly, if any part of it is not a number it needs to be in quotations (as it is a string).

Comment: There are only numbers, i've put on quitations just to be sure and there's no change.